# Get changes in JQuery Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My apologies if this seems dumb, but how would implement a function when the Ajax data changed from the last request?

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $.get("feed", function(data){
         if (data.changed) {
             $('#feed').html(data);
         }
    });
}, 500);
```

Comment: Compare it to the data from the last request..

Comment: In response of your call, status of whether info is change sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this to cache your data and compare it after each request?

```
var data;

window.setInterval(function(){
    $.get("feed", function(newData){
         if (data !== newData) {
            data = newData;
            $('#feed').html(data);
         }
    });
}, 500);
```

Also, 500ms is very regular to be checking requests, I'd advise changing that to 5000ms or something.